# What would I use to regulate raise/lower temperature in an AC 40 watt device's heating element?

Tags: voltage-regulator, temperature, dimmer, rheostat

It's for a resin burner--frankincense etc--that doesn't have a temperature regulator so it burns too hot. I don't need to know an actual temperature, just to be able to raise/lower the temp'. Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information. Is it mains powered? You're in USA, so 120 V? If so an old-fashioned dimmer switch would work.

Comment: A dimmer control seems to the easiest solution.

Comment: Get a variac (aka auto-transformer).

Comment: In the 70’s they just used a Triac dimmer and calibrate temp daily in Production in Japan for soldering iron temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it mains-powered, then most  lamp dimmers will work. For example (for US):

http://www.lutron.com/en-US/HeroImages/CredenzaLampDim_01_hero.png

Comment: Thank you so much for including that link because I was wondering if I could use that type of dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can halve the power by putting a diode in series. Often times this will do it.

Once caveat is if your heater actually uses a PTC heating element. This is quite common for small things you want to not overheat.

It becomes very difficult to lower the temperature by changing duty-cycle, as the PTC is self regulating.

Comment: Thinking ahead that the heating element may fail in the future I've been looking at little heating elements, many are ptc, should I avoid that type if I'm going to be using a lamp dimmer?

Comment: You can always experiment, just be aware that the ptc type might prove to not work. A problem is that PTC is probably the right way to make this product. So you might be choosing between a better one, and a worse one, that you can fiddle with.